# Terraform : Unable to create cloudwatch alarm on a instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to create a cloudwatch alarm as follows:

```
module "superb_queue_api-a" {
  source = "../../Modules/Services"

  no_of_inst    = 1
  ami_id        = "${data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnets       = "${data.terraform_remote_state.state_pull.prod-pvt-sub-a}"
  key           = "sup_queue_inst"
  sec-group     = ["${aws_security_group.ec2_sg.id}"]
  tp            = "${var.is_production ? true : false}"

  instance-name = "sup-queue-api-a"
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "queue_1" {
  alarm_name          = "sup-queue-api-a"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  metric_name         = "CPUUtilization"
  namespace           = "AWS/EC2"
  period              = "120"
  statistic           = "Average"
  threshold           = "90"

  dimensions {
    InstanceId = "${module.superb_queue_api-a.ec2-instance}"
  }

  alarm_description = "This metric monitors ec2 cpu utilization"
  alarm_actions     = ["${var.terraform_elb_name}"]
}
```

I am having the following module to spin instance

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2_instances" {
  count = "${var.no_of_inst}"

  #count         = "${var.countt}"
  ami           = "${var.ami_id}"
  instance_type = "${var.instance_type}"

  #vpc_id        = "${var.vpc}"
  subnet_id = "${var.subnets}"
  key_name  = "${var.key}"

  vpc_security_group_ids  = ["${var.sec-group}"]
  disable_api_termination = "${var.tp}"

  root_block_device {
    volume_size = 100
    volume_type = "gp2"
  }

  tags {
    Name = "${var.instance-name}"
  }
}
```

The output.tf has the following

```
output "ec2-instance" {
  value = "${aws_instance.ec2_instances.*.id}"
}

output "private_ip" {
  value = "${aws_instance.ec2_instances.*.private_ip}"
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.queue_1: dimensions (InstanceId): '' expected type 'string', got unconvertible type '[]interface {}'
```

Can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that  module.superb_queue_api-a.ec2-instance is an array, because that module is creating more than one instance, and the output of the module is an array with the ids of all instances.

I've adapted the code so it creates an alarm for every instance:

```
 resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "queue_1" {
  count  = "${length(module.superb_queue_api-a.ec2-instance)}"

  alarm_name          = "sup-queue-api-a-${module.superb_queue_api-a.ec2-instance[count.index]}"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  metric_name         = "CPUUtilization"
  namespace           = "AWS/EC2"
  period              = "120"
  statistic           = "Average"
  threshold           = "90"

  dimensions {
    InstanceId = "${module.superb_queue_api-a.ec2-instance[count.index]}"
  }

  alarm_description = "This metric monitors ec2 cpu utilization"
  alarm_actions     = ["${var.terraform_elb_name}"]
}
```

Comment: okay looks right, just one more thing if i have want to have 2 cloudwatch alarm ,won't this update the same instance?

Comment: I don't understand sorry, you want to create one more alarm like this one right? What's the exact problem?